# DisplayManager - get local Display name

Tags: android

I want to get a local Display name. I need this to pair information about Display and device role in my application.

How to get local Display name/id?

Answer (score 0):

DisplayManager#getDisplays() returns Display[] which you can iterate over and get the name

Comment: Yes i know about it. But i need to know my local display name.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "local display". Do you mean primary default display?

Comment: The display name of device my application is running. I need to send a message: CONNECT ME which will contain name.

Comment: I am still not clear on what you mean. However check out android.os.Build#Model

Comment: The display name of device my application is running. I do not know how to clarify this.